# Jhipster Swagger configuration

Tags: swagger, jhipster, swagger-ui

How to override Jhipster swagger configuration in a microservice project to change the /api path in the backend and update gateway Swagger UI accordingly ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting `default-include-pattern` in `swagger` section of your config file (probably `application.yml`)?

Default setting is `/api/.*`. For my project I changed it to `/(api|io)/.*` (its a regex) to include `api` and `io` paths.

Answer (score 0):

As of [JHipster 7.0](https://www.jhipster.tech/2021/03/21/jhipster-release-7.0.0.html), the following changes were made to the backend:

- swagger maven profile becomes **api-docs**
- jhipster.swagger property becomes **jhipster.api-docs**

In order to enable swagger api and to change the default uri pattern I had to:

1 - Enable the maven `api-docs` profile

2 - Add the following property under to application.yml *(replace with your api path)*:

```
jhipster:

  api-docs:
    default-include-pattern: /api-new-path/.*
```

Comment: basePath seems to be missing in the output swagger when using the new version of jHipster